# Generate sequence from a value using R

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
date    |country   | crisis | 
2011 q2 |   AT     |    0   |
2011 q3 |   AT     |    0   |
2011 q4 |   AT     |    1   |
2012 q1 |   AT     |    0   |
2012 q2 |   AT     |    1   | 
2011 q1 |   BE     |    0   |
2011 q3 |   BE     |    0   |
2011 q4 |   BE     |    0   |
2012 q1 |   BE     |    1   |
2012 q2 |   BE     |    0   |
```

And I would like to compute another variable for each country-crisis pair that is 0 when crisis is 1 and then create a sequence starting from zero, like this

```
date    |country   | crisis | AT_crisis1 | AT_crisis2 | BE_crisis 1
2011 q2 |   AT     |    0   |  -2        |     -4     |    NA
2011 q3 |   AT     |    0   |  -1        |     -3     |    NA
2011 q4 |   AT     |    1   |   0        |     -2     |    NA
2012 q1 |   AT     |    0   |   1        |     -1     |    NA
2012 q2 |   AT     |    1   |   2        |      0     |    NA
2011 q1 |   BE     |    0   |   NA       |     NA     |    -3
2011 q3 |   BE     |    0   |   NA       |     NA     |    -2
2011 q4 |   BE     |    0   |   NA       |     NA     |    -1
2012 q1 |   BE     |    1   |   NA       |     NA     |     0
2012 q2 |   BE     |    0   |   NA       |     NA     |    +1
```

Here a reproducible example for the first dataset

```
library(zoo)

date <- c("2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2012Q1","2012Q2","2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2012Q1","2012Q2")
date <- as.yearqtr(date)
country <- c("AT","AT","AT","AT","AT","BE","BE","BE","BE","BE")
crisis <- c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)

df <- data.frame(date, country, crisis)
```

Thank you.

Comment: In your expected output I don't see any variable being systematically 0 when crisis is 1, nor any sequence from -24 to 24, nor any sequence starting from 0. Can you explain how these columns are computed ?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I removed the reference to +- 24, the variable is systematically 0 for each country - crisis pair.  If you take the first appearance of the crisis (value 1) for the country AT the AT-crisis1 is equal to 0 when the first value of crisis is 1

Comment: I got it now :), see answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way :

```r
library(zoo)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
library(tidyverse)
date <- c("2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2012Q1","2012Q2","2011Q2","2011Q3","2011Q4","2012Q1","2012Q2")
date <- as.yearqtr(date)
country <- c("AT","AT","AT","AT","AT","BE","BE","BE","BE","BE")
crisis <- c(0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0)
df <- data.frame(date, country, crisis)

df %>%
  mutate_at("date", as.character) %>% # as it's a factor in sample data
  group_split(country) %>%
  map_dfr(~imap_dfr(which(.$crisis==1), ~mutate(..3, key =.y, value = seq(1-.,len = nrow(..3))), .)) %>%
  unite(key, country, key, sep = "_crisis", remove = FALSE) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  arrange(country, date)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#>    date    country crisis AT_crisis1 AT_crisis2 BE_crisis1
#>    <chr>   <fct>    <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 2011 Q2 AT           0         -2         -4         NA
#>  2 2011 Q3 AT           0         -1         -3         NA
#>  3 2011 Q4 AT           1          0         -2         NA
#>  4 2012 Q1 AT           0          1         -1         NA
#>  5 2012 Q2 AT           1          2          0         NA
#>  6 2011 Q2 BE           0         NA         NA         -3
#>  7 2011 Q3 BE           0         NA         NA         -2
#>  8 2011 Q4 BE           0         NA         NA         -1
#>  9 2012 Q1 BE           1         NA         NA          0
#> 10 2012 Q2 BE           0         NA         NA          1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The double map call is probably a bit intimidating, here's what it does :

- The outside map call applies a transformation on each country dataframe created by split, and binds them together
- the second map call loops on values of `which(crisis)`, we use an `imap` function to keep track of the index too because we need it to name the column (store it in `key` at this step). For each `which` value we create a dataframe with a `value` column containing the sequence that will be moved to the new columns later, for this we need the data frame object, which we pass as a 3rd parameter, hence the last `.` of the line, and the `..3` in the call.

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(setDT(df)[, {
        idx <- .SD[crisis==1L, which=TRUE]
        names(idx) <- paste0(.BY$country, "_crisis", seq_along(idx))

        .(.(c(country=.BY$country, .SD, 
            lapply(idx, function(k) seq_len(.N) - k))))
    },
    country]$V1, 
use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

output:

```
    country    date crisis AT_crisis1 AT_crisis2 BE_crisis1
 1:      AT 2011 Q2      0         -2         -4         NA
 2:      AT 2011 Q3      0         -1         -3         NA
 3:      AT 2011 Q4      1          0         -2         NA
 4:      AT 2012 Q1      0          1         -1         NA
 5:      AT 2012 Q2      1          2          0         NA
 6:      BE 2011 Q2      0         NA         NA         -3
 7:      BE 2011 Q3      0         NA         NA         -2
 8:      BE 2011 Q4      0         NA         NA         -1
 9:      BE 2012 Q1      1         NA         NA          0
10:      BE 2012 Q2      0         NA         NA          1
```

Comment: This is a great  use case of nesting/unnesting with data.table!

Comment: I think MichaelChirico is working on it https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4156